# Sci-fi comic from the 90s or 2000s; main character is a girl with white skin and black markings around her eyes

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to bring to mind this comic I read years ago. I remember the cover very clearly, at least it seems clear even if the image has been corrupted over the years.

A girl on a bike, or halftrack bike or maybe a speeder, some small open vehicle with handlebars, on snowy ground like tundra. I think it was a snow planet. It's drawn from above, like a crane shot in a movie, and she's looking up at the "camera" wearing, I think, a leather 'pilot's cap' and goggles and maybe a bomber jacket. She's meant to be some kind of near-human alien, I think, of a style I've seen pop up for several races in *Star Wars* comics (especially not unlike Aurra Sing): paper-white skin, with black markings.

The way I'm picturing the markings is black circles around her whole eyes, like a panda. It could also have been black stripes on her cheeks. I have separate memories of the markings and I think I'm conflating this comic with something else I read.

I'm pretty sure she was a bounty hunter, or something like that, flying around in space in her own ship. I don't really remember any story details, unfortunately– it's always the visuals that stick with me.

I'm pretty sure it would be from the late 90s or the 2000s, based on my memory of the art style.

Comment: Are you talking about Domino? She's a character from X-Men, and has the features you have described here.

Comment: Sure seems similar but I don't remember it being X-Men (I read a lot of other X-Men and other superhero comics around then too, and recall this being distinct) and I think it was more of a space-age kind of sci fi story. 

also I'm pretty sure she had the markings on both eyes. And might have been younger?

Answer (score 4):

Zero doubt here: you're thinking of the English cover of "Gearing Up", the third volume of [*Wake*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_(comics)), originally published in France in 2000 and translated in English in 2002.

[image: protagonist looking at the sky, while riding a motorbike in a snowy landscape]

---

I found it because I read this series (it's absolutely excellent by the way). In some volumes, Nävis (the protagonist) has to wear a panda-like disguise, which your description reminded me of. In fact, I had [the original French cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL82H.jpg) in mind, which did have Nävis dressed in leather, but no bike; I thought to check if maybe the cover got changed for foreign versions.